# Gamemaker rooms empty even though there are objects in the room

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I made a game, it worked earlier today. right now though, my main menu works just fine if i compile for javascript, but when i go to any other room, it's just a black screen, but if i compile for windows, the buttons don't work at all. nothing happens when i click on them. and if make any other room the starter room, the game just doesn't load at all, just a little black rectangle in the edge of the screen, as shown in this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlG0N.png)

if you need more details/screenshots, PLEASE ASK ME

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the black square is about, but a black screen upon entering a room usually indicates the code being stuck in a loop i.e. a while/for/until loop (as it never reaches the stage where it draws whatever sprites and backgrounds). Freezing also indicates such. I suggest placing debug points immediately after every while/for/until loop in your code and running debug mode, removing the debug points when you hit them, until you never hit one of the debug points, which means that is the loop the computer is getting stuck in.